# Create radio button dynamically in magento

Tags: javascript, php, magento-1.7

I am new in magento,i have to develop extension in magento, in that extension i need to be create dynamically radio button i used following code in javascript in edit.phtml

```
function createRadio(){
  var label = document.createElement("label");
             var element = document.createElement("input");

            //Assign different attributes to the element.
             element.setAttribute("type", 'radio');
             element.setAttribute("value",array_resp);
             element.setAttribute("name", 'radio');

             label.appendChild(element);
             label.innerHTML += "Matched Address("+j+"):-"+array_resp;
             document.body.appendChild(label);
}
```

And used button:-

```
<input type="button" onclick="createRadio()" value="Create radio" />
```

for calling above function . But it not works.whats wrong in it?please any magento expert give me sugestion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any error on browser console? And `array_resp` and `j` are not null right?

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/UqHGK/144/)**

Be sure that you are including js function correctly. You can check your browser console for any specific error. Also, check your variables `array_resp` and `j` is valid.

I assume your variables like;

`array_resp = b`, and `j = a`;

and you can use;

**HTML:**

**JS**

```
window.createRadio = function() {
            var label = document.createElement("label");
             var element = document.createElement("input");

            //Assign different attributes to the element.
             element.setAttribute("type", 'radio');
             element.setAttribute("value","b");
             element.setAttribute("name", 'radio');

             label.appendChild(element);
             label.innerHTML += "Matched Address(a):-b";
             document.body.appendChild(label);
}
```